# HDD Broken? Windows prompts to initialize the disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have Seagate Barracuda 2tb hard disk which has been working happily in a NAS for a year or so. Unfortunately the disk now appears to be broken as the NAS doesn't recognise it.

I've tried plugging it into my laptop and desktop and both know its there in Disk Management but it appears as 'not initalized'. I believe initializing it will reduce my chances of recovering the data from it so I've not gone down that path yet. I've tried various tools such as MiniTool Partition Wizard, Partition Find & Mount and Easeus Partition Manager but none of them recognise the disk as being present so don't give me any recovery options.

I've also tried booting into Ubuntu just to see if that could see it, but alas no.

Can anyone suggest any alternative approaches I could take to getting it in any sort of working state? I'm a bit pessimistic given how it's gone so far, but maybe all is not lost.

Comment: You have tried the good tools and the alternatives you might have to accept the files can't be restored

Comment: Sounds like the partition table is toast, However, physically, the drive may be good. Corruption happens from time to time, Give it a good DBAN and use it in a non-mission-critical way.

Comment: Have you tried [`testdisk`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)?

Comment: Hi, I tried testdisk in Ubuntu and just tried the Windows version - both behave as others, where the problem drive isn't even listed unfortunately

Comment: If the disk is still visible on the BIOS, you may want to try [Spinrite](https://www.grc.com/cs/prepurch.htm) as there are lots of testimonials about how it manages to "resurrect near-death drives" so to say.

Comment: I would suggest you to try steller phonix data recovery software. It is very good. If disk is detecting in BIOS then might be you will recover your data

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The BIOS isn't detecting it unfortunately, even though Windows does so I don't think these tools will work either :(